# What's the name of the transformation that can remove horizontal convergence from a picture?

Tags: transformations, camera, distortion

Say that you are taking pictures from a street like this one:
[image]

As you can see, the picture is taken perpendicular to the direction of the street.

The problem is that cars at the left look as if they are going East South:

[image]

And cars at the right look as if they are going East North:

[image]

Only when they're right in front of you, the cars look like going simply East:

[image]

As I understand, the name for this phenomena is called "Horizontal Convergence". How could you remove this phenomena from a picture? That is, how can I transform the image so that all the cars look like going simply to the East no matter their horizontal position.

To read about a "vertical congergence": https://digital-photography-school.com/how-to-overcome-the-problem-of-converging-verticals/

Comment: Use a small field of view lens and move further away. It's perspective, unless you are talking about some kind of extra lens distortion too. See telephoto on wikipedia.

Comment: @lightxbulb thanks for the suggestion, but I’m looking for a transformation in software